# Change Magento Default Quantity, but not Minimum

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a need to by default when adding a product, in this case tires to default to a quantity of 4. But at the same time I don't want the minimum to be 4 -- because if I do that, then if you only wanted one tire then you get an error.

Any help?

Comment: Have you considered setting an attribute (non filterable)?  Say call it defaultQty -- call that attribute in Magento, check to see if it's greater than 1, then if it is, set your quantity "value" on your form `<input>` field to the filters result.  If it's not set, default to 1 on the `<input>` field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to set the qty field to 4 when the page load. To make it more admin friendly you could create a new product attribute to store the default qty and new product attribue set for product you want to change the default values for and only update the qty if both are true.

> $("qty").value = 4

(you would have to add additional logic for when customer is editing their order on the product page)

or you could modifying the add to cart template see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6117/

Answer (score 0):

I had your exact same problem. 
You need to add the "qty" parameter to the url your "Add to Cart" button makes.
So from:

```
http://your.site.com/checkout/cart/add/product/51/
```

to

```
http://your.site.com/checkout/cart/add/product/51/qty/4
```

In other words, in your

```
app/design/frontend/default/[youthemefoldername]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

file, you need to substitute:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

with:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>qty/4')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

EDIT:
Look here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22185/ for more info.